# Select between 3 different querys and use the one with results

Tags: php, mysql, database

Good day everyone,

i want to know the best way to select between 3 different querys and use the one with results...

```
    Select * from table where lugar in (1, 2, 3)
```

or

```
    Select * from table where lugar in (4, 5, 6)
```

or

```
    Select * from table where lugar in (7, 8, 9, 10)
```

can i use something like a switch operator?

I need more ideas to do it...

I dont use "if" because the query with results have to use a lot of code...

Thanks in advance!

Mario Mata.

Comment: Combine the three `IN` clauses into one?

Comment: why not `Select * from table where lugar in (1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this

```
$var_val="abc";
switch ($var_val)
{
  case "aa":
   $qry = "Select * from table where lugar in (1, 2, 3)";
   break;
 case "abc":
   $qry = "Select * from table where lugar in (4, 5, 6)";
   break;
 case "cc":
   $qry = "Select * from table where lugar in (7, 8, 9,10)";
   break;
 default:
   $qry = "Select * from table";
}
```

Comment: well, i can use this but first i need to verify if the query gives me back results...

Comment: means, what are you saying?

Comment: i need to compare first which query gives me results, the i'll use that query...

Comment: first tell me,what is the value of switch `($var_val)` in your case?then i can say something

Comment: i don't have a switch... i'm trying to get ideas of how to choose between 3 different querys... i mean use the one with results...

Comment: Here if your variable value is in any of the case then the `$qry` variable is the this case value.and matched case qry get executed and gives result.Like here, `$var_val="abc";` so the value of query is `$qry = "Select * from table where lugar in (4, 5, 6)";` and this will executed and give result.if  value is not matched in any case then default query gets executed.

Comment: thaks for the full guide to understand this code... i have been triying for almos a week to reduce my coding and this will help me a lot!!!

Comment: Welcome :) You understand my explanation,this is lot for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a array variable. Then change the content of the array in the switch, instead of the SELECT `statement`

```php
switch($something) {
    case 'a':
        $in = array(1,2,3);            
        break;
    case 'b':
        $in = array(4,5,6);            
        break;
    case 'c':
        $in = array(7,8,9,10);            
        break;
    default:
        $in = array(1,2,3);
}
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE lugar IN ($in)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you're really bound to use if statement for that and it best suits your problem

```
$query = mysql_query('Select * from table where lugar in (1, 2, 3)');
if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
//this will check if there was a result on a given query
}
```

just loop around to achieve the other too.. good day

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking.

Comment: Amal it's rigth, i dont want to use if statements.. thx anyway